Whats the difference between async/await fetch with https + chunks?
I have read an api from a third party and they have some examples and in one example I saw this:
    var options = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'hostname': 'xxxx',
      'path': '/sms/2/text/advanced',
      'headers': {
          'Authorization': 'App xxx',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      'maxRedirects': 20
  };

var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
    var chunks = [];

    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", function (chunk) {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        console.log(body.toString());
    });

    res.on("error", function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
});

var postData = JSON.stringify({
    "messages": [
        {
            "destinations": [{"to":"xxxxx211"}],
            "from": "ServiceSMS",
            "text": "Congratulations on sending your first message.\nGo ahead and check the delivery report in the next step."
        }
    ]
});

req.write(postData);

req.end();

So I can also this write with async await and fetch  but whats the main difference here and what would be better to use ? async await fetch or this example above

Can you show both code you want to differentiate?

The question lacks the context. How do you intend to use this code? async/await obviously fits into promise control flow. It's not shown how the chunks are used but since you collect them, it's safe to assume that you don't benefit from processing a response in chunks
